# Your input is welcome for the Anniversary blog

Tags: discussion

Chess Stack Exchange is turning 10 years old this quarter, so it's time for <s>a big party</s> an entry in [Stack Exchange's quarterly anniversary blog post](https://stackoverflow.blog/2022/03/16/celebrating-the-stack-exchange-site-that-turned-ten-years-old-in-q1-2022/)! As you can see, we'll be getting a paragraph describing our site and community, together with one or a couple of interesting questions.

We (the moderators and staff) know you'll come up with some ideas about this; please post them as answers to this question, and vote on submissions by other users. To make voting easier, please nominate one interesting question per answer. Ideas for the paragraph are welcome as well, in a separate answer (which can be edited/commented on by other users). Otherwise I'll try to draft one in the coming week (and post it as an answer as well).

Answer (score 5):

#### Paragraph idea

---

[Chess](https://chess.stackexchange.com/)

Many Stack Exchange users love a good game now and then, and it's no wonder that they regularly check out our community. We can help you improve both your gameplay and your self-made chess engine. If you're interested in the history, present or future of chess, visiting Chess Stack Exchange is definitely the right move.

---

(sorry, couldn't resist the puns ...)

Answer (score 4):

#### Question idea

[How has chess managed to remain a competitive sport despite engine dominance?](https://chess.stackexchange.com/q/34635/7297)

It's always good to see why your sport is still relevant, and there are various answers covering different aspects of the topic.

Answer (score 2):

#### Question idea

[What are examples of very aggressive openings?](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/75/what-are-examples-of-very-aggressive-openings)

Not only is this the most upvoted and second most viewed question on chess.SE, it gives people an idea of the "openings" in chess! (aggressive I might add) :)

Answer (score 1):

#### Question idea

[Fastest possible checkmate by en passant](https://chess.stackexchange.com/q/21492/7297)

A large part of the questions on our site is about puzzles, problems and records. This is one with a couple of good answers, with a 'definitive' answer and an answer to a natural extension of the question.

Answer (score 1):

#### Question idea

[With only the King left, how can you get a draw?](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/8/with-only-the-king-left-how-can-you-get-a-draw)

A lot of views, and an interesting element of chess.